# FlowLayout Centering a label?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, flowlayout

I am making a form by using `FlowLayout`. The GUI of the form is shown below:

```
Name: <textField>
    Age: <textfiedl>
    Gender: Male[] Female[]
Email: <textField>
```

For gender, the options are radio buttons. As you can see, the labels for age and gender should be centered. How can I do this using `FlowLayout`?

Answer (score 2):

If the whole form is created using BoxLayout, one oriented as `BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS`, then if each "line" of the form is a JPanel that uses FlowLayout, the components that they held should be centered by default, since JPanel uses `new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5)` as its default layout (actually it uses `new FlowLayout()`, but the default values for this constructor are as above -- CENTER orientation with horizontal and vertical gaps of 5).

Another option is to use a GridBagLayout, and alter the constraints' FILL and `weighty` properties for the component on each row.

For example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LayoutExample extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextField ageField = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField emailField = new JTextField(10);
    private ButtonGroup sexBtnGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    private JRadioButton maleBtn = new JRadioButton("Male");
    private JRadioButton femaleBtn = new JRadioButton("Female");

    public LayoutExample() {
        JPanel agePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 5, 5));
        agePanel.add(new JLabel("Age:"));
        agePanel.add(ageField);

        sexBtnGroup.add(maleBtn);
        sexBtnGroup.add(femaleBtn);;
        JPanel sexSelectionPanel = new JPanel();
        sexSelectionPanel.add(new JLabel("Select Sex:"));
        sexSelectionPanel.add(maleBtn);
        sexSelectionPanel.add(femaleBtn);

        JPanel emailPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 5, 5));
        emailPanel.add(new JLabel("Email:"));
        emailPanel.add(emailField);

        int gap = 10;
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(gap, gap, gap, gap));
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        add(agePanel);
        add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
        add(sexSelectionPanel);
        add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
        add(emailPanel);        
    }

    // make it stretch horizontally to see placement
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension superSize = super.getPreferredSize();
        int width = (3 * superSize.width) / 2;
        int height = superSize.height;
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        LayoutExample mainPanel = new LayoutExample();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("LayoutExample");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

Example 2 using a GridBagLayout:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LayoutExample2 extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextField ageField = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField emailField = new JTextField(10);
    private ButtonGroup sexBtnGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    private JRadioButton maleBtn = new JRadioButton("Male");
    private JRadioButton femaleBtn = new JRadioButton("Female");

    public LayoutExample2() {

        JPanel sexSelectPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 5));
        sexBtnGroup.add(maleBtn);
        sexSelectPanel.add(maleBtn);
        sexBtnGroup.add(femaleBtn);
        sexSelectPanel.add(femaleBtn);

        int gap = 10;
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(gap, gap, gap, gap));
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        add(new JLabel("Age:"), createGbc(0, 0));
        add(ageField, createGbc(1, 0));

        add(new JLabel("Sex:"), createGbc(0, 1));
        add(sexSelectPanel, createGbc(1, 1));

        add(new JLabel("Email:"), createGbc(0, 2));
        add(emailField, createGbc(1, 2));
    }

    private static GridBagConstraints createGbc(int x, int y) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = y;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        int ins = 4;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(ins, ins, ins, ins);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        return gbc;
    }

    // make it stretch horizontally to see placement
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension superSize = super.getPreferredSize();
        int width = (4 * superSize.width) / 3;
        int height = superSize.height;
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        LayoutExample2 mainPanel = new LayoutExample2();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("LayoutExample");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: If i create each line as a separate panel, how can I centre the label age and gender? By using panel.setallignement(FlowLayout.Centre).

Comment: @user10600161: it is already centered by default. You really will want to post your [mre] code to see what you're doing that is or is not working.

Comment: @user10600161: please see addition to answer

Comment: OP: *"How can I do this using `FlowLayout`?"* I am guessing you've understood from two answers, *neither* of which *only* used flow layout, that flow layout by itself is unable to fulfill the requirement.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: yes, so would I. I usually use Grid Bag to create such forms, creating and then using a utility method to facilitate the creation of a GridBagConstraint object for each item added.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way (of a plethora of ways it might be done). Layout details in titled borders.

[image]

Note: For anything to do with selecting a number, it's better to offer the user a spinner.

Comment: Nicely done. 1+. Original poster: this is the better and more complete solution

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter Your suggestions were good as well. I'd go with `GridBagLayout` since I could not be bothered working out how to make `BoxLayout` work to my needs, and with GBL it could all be achieved using a single panel.